# How can I get Client IP?ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ip

I use HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and REMOTE_ADDR server variables to get the client IP. If I use Chrome:

```
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR = "";
REMOTE_ADDR  = returns ipv4
```

If I use another browser:

```
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR = "";
REMOTE_ADDR  = returns ipv6
```

How can I get ipv4 anywhere???

UPDATE: I turned off IPv6 support on the server and REMOTE_ADDR always return ipv4

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dim ClientIP As String = Request.UserHostAddress` to get the ip address

[Credit to this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102847/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/071807-1.aspx)

For complete code http://tutorialgenius.blogspot.in/2010/09/aspnet-get-ipv4-address-even-if-user-is.html

Using this code we can find IP address of visitor even if visitor is behind any proxy([Reference](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2008/12/finding-ip-address-behind-proxy-using-c.html))

```
public string IpAddress()
{
string strIpAddress;
strIpAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (strIpAddress == null)
{
strIpAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
return strIpAddress;
}
```

Comment: Request.UserHostAddress also returns Ipv6

Comment: returns server ip, but i need client ip            foreach (IPAddress IPA in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
    {
      if (IPA.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
      {
        IP4Address = IPA.ToString();
        break;
      }
    }

Comment: But I used this code. Only chrome returns in REMOTE_ADDR ipv4